# Calculus. Why are these statements equal?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm taking calculus and I've been stumped on this for a while now, Google isn't helping because idk what to search for... OK my question is about the change in a quotient.
$$
\delta\left(\frac {u}{v}\right) = \frac {(u+\delta {u} )}{(v + \delta {v})} - \frac {u}{v}
$$

How is that equal to this?
$$
\frac {u(t + \delta {t})} {v(t + \delta {t})} - \frac {u(t)} {v(t)}
$$
where $u$ is a function, $v$ is a function, $t$ is an arbitrary variable.
Sorry idk if this will format the math right. First post on SE.

I think I'm having trouble understanding the notation or something. Thanks.

Comment: See here for how to format:
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It's equal if you put parenthesis correctly $(u+ \delta u) / (v+\delta v).$

Comment: Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Fixed the formatting,I think-is that what you intended? Because I can't answer the question if I don't know what you're asking......

Comment: It looks correct except I'm using a capital delta. Idk if that makes a difference.

Comment: I changed it to make look just like what I have in front of me.

Comment: You just want to know how the Quotient Rule is derived , right?

Answer (score 3):

If $u=u(t), v=v(t)$, then

$$△u=u(t+△t)-u(t),\quad △v=v(t+△t)-v(t)$$

The differential form is

$$△(\dfrac{u} {v})=\dfrac{u+△u} {v+△v}-\dfrac{u} {v}=\dfrac{(u+△u)v-u(v+△v)} {(v+△v)v}=\dfrac{△u v-u△v} {(v+△v)v}$$

So the derivative is

$$\lim \limits_{t \to 0}\dfrac{△(\dfrac{u} {v})} {△t} =\lim \limits_{t \to 0}\dfrac{△u v-u△v} {(v+△v)v△t}=\lim \limits_{t \to 0}\dfrac{\dfrac{△u} {△t} v-u\dfrac{△v} {△t}} {(v+△v)v}=\dfrac{u'v-uv'} {v^2}$$

Comment: Just so you know, it's better instead of copy-and-pasting the triangle symbol, to write out the math code for the symbol you want, which in this case is $\text{ \Delta }$ for $\Delta$.  Be careful not to write $\text{ \delta }$, which produces the lower case Greek letter $\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

By definition,

$$\delta u(t)=u(t+\delta t)-u(t),$$then obviously

$$u(t+\delta t)=u(t)+\delta u(t).$$

---

So
$$\frac{u(t+\delta t)}{v(t+\delta t)}-\frac{u(t)}{v(t)}=\frac{u(t)+\delta u(t)}{v(t)+\delta v(t)}-\frac{u(t)}{v(t)}=\frac{\delta u(t)v(t)-u(t)\delta v(t)}{v^2(t)+v(t)\delta v(t)}\to\frac{\delta u(t)v(t)-u(t)\delta v(t)}{v^2(t)},$$

and 
$$\left(\frac{u(t)}{v(t)}\right)'=\frac{u'(t)v(t)-u(t)v'(t)}{v^2(t)}.$$